# Am I supposed to have to end every elseif block?

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm a bit confused about elseif blocks in Lua. On the [official Lua tutorial thing](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.1.html) it shows that only 1 end is needed for a whole if block. However, in my code, I'm getting an error whenever I don't add a close for every elseif I have in my if. Here's my code with all the ends:

```
  if direction == 1 then
    snakeHead.y = snakeHead.y - 2
  else if direction == 2 then
    snakeHead.x = snakeHead.x + 2
  else if direction == 3 then
    snakeHead.y = snakeHead.y - 2
  else if direction == 4 then
    snakeHead.x = snakeHead.x - 2
  end
  end
  end
  end
```

Also, this code is in Love2D although that may be completely unrelated to the issue.

Comment: Try changing `else if` to `elseif`, ie. lose the space between the two keywords.

Comment: You're creating `else` blocks with nested if statements, not using `elseif`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the tutorial you refer to carefully, you will see you need to use `elseif` and not `else if`. That is, it's a single keyword, not two.

Comment: yeah i literally realized it right now. so used to java i instinctively put a space there. thanks for the help though

Comment: No problem at all. It's a common enough issue. There's `else if` (C, Java, etc.), `elseif` (PHP, lua), elsif (Perl, Ruby), elif (bash) and probably others.